# Microsoft graph api: Some users get a 403 when using my app, others don't, why?

Tags: permissions, microsoft-graph-api

## Problem

I get

> Microsoft\Graph\Exception\GraphException: [0]: Received 403 for call
> to
> [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats/[id]@unq.gbl.spaces/members](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats/%5Bid%5D@unq.gbl.spaces/members)

I fail to understand why.

---

## Research

### permissions in Azure

[image]

### how the exception appears in my queue

[image]

### Additional information

Just to be clear: this same request with other users of our company is working, so it's not something that always fails. It might be worth noting that the permissions starting with Chat are from the beta version of the graph api. Also retrieving info about the user (ownUser getGivenName) is working for all users.

### App scopes

The scopes defined in the application are:

> openid
> profile
> offline_access
> user.read
> mailboxsettings.read
> calendars.readwrite
> Chat.ReadBasic
> Chat.Read
> Chat.ReadWrite

### Response of the server

The response completely:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-05-04T12:05:41",
            "request-id": "xxxxxxx-f7ea-4912-a23b-676002d0912d",
            "client-request-id": "xxxxxxx-f7ea-4912-a23b-676002d0912d"
        }
    }
}
```

The response headers also don't reveal anything:

[image]

### Also tried

I also tried re-visiting [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=[id]](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=%5Bid%5D) and give my (admin) consent, however this doesn't change anything.

### JWT token

Also I decoded both a working users jwt token and a non-working one and they have the same scp (scopes) configured. [Here is the diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/a8e6NcaA)

### used endpoints

- `/me/chats`
- `/me`
- `/me/chats/$chatId/messages`
- `/me/chats/$chatId/members`

Comment: What admins are trying to access the event - and are they attendees or owners of the chat?

Comment: @Diana They are owners. My application is creating backups of teams chats of the logged in user. It's working for most of the users, just for some it gives the 403 forbidden, while the required permissions stay the same. It's a real headscratcher.

Comment: Would you share the request-id for further debugging? I can see you've added the complete response to the question.

Comment: @Diana the request id is `dd4afa4a-f7ea-4912-a23b-676002d0912d`, I doubt this id is dangerous to post in any way, however I tried to keep as mich private as possible

Comment: I think this is caused by the lack of `Office365 license` for your users. Try to grant Office365 license to your users before calling the api.

Comment: @CarlZhao Every employee has a working office365 license

Comment: Did you create a group chat? Is each user an `owner` role?

Comment: Your token looks okay. Are your users all working accounts?

Comment: @CarlZhao Yes it's just their own teams messages, also the error occurs already when [listing the chats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). They are all still working accounts, the backup is needed because they will be moved to a new tennant.

Comment: There is a very strange thing, the list of users chat does not support application permissions, then you cannot use the `/users` endpoint. However, the documentation uses the `/users` endpoint as an example, which I think is problematic.

Comment: @CarlZhao I just use the endpoints with `/me` never for another user.

Comment: I just did a test and no error was reported. You can try using the Graph Explorer tool to see how it turns out.   https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: @CarlZhao I did, but it might be worth a shot to ask one of my collegues who have failing accounts to do so.

Comment: I now have verifaction it's only happening on the members call...

Comment: Have you found the cause of the error?

Comment: Not really, but it might pay off to not call members (which I use if the chat has no name or 1:1)

Answer (score 0):

Just some observations and workarounds to help out others who come on this post through google:

- Only the `/me/chats/$chatId/members` fails, without an apparant reason. It might be a mistake in in the beta implementation. Maybe it's better to use the `$expand` argument to see them to mitigate this problem.
- for another subgroup of users retrieving all the chats with the endpoint `/me/chats` with the [php sdk](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php) also fails with the [recommended code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/wiki/Paging-through-Collections)

```php
  public function listChats(): array
    {
        $graph = $this->getGraph();
        $chats = [];
        $response = $graph->setApiVersion("beta")
            ->createCollectionRequest("GET", "/me/chats")
            ->setReturnType(Chat::class);
        while (!$response->isEnd()) {
            $chats = array_merge($chats, $response->getPage());
        }

        return $chats;
    }
```

because the while loop never stops. `@odata.nextLink` is always present in the response for these users. Probably also a bug as by design the sdk checks if it's present.

```php
  $maxRequests = 10;
   while (!$response->isEnd() && $maxRequests > 0) {
     $chats = array_merge($chats, $response->getPage());
     $maxRequests--;
   }
```